# Writing a volume over time function in R with options for; faceted or a list of plots

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, functional-programming, facet

I am writing an R function that plots a group variables' volume over time using some ggplot2 functionality, I have an argument for plot_type = "facet" or "list". Currently the facet plot renders how I would like it to, but the list of plots doesn't ascribe the same(or any) colour to the group variables as in the facet plot. I'm aware that it could just be an issue with my order of code execution causing the list of plots to not carry over the same colours but its not immediately obvious to me where this has occurred, if anyone can point it out that would be great!

Here is the function in its current state, I am using `if` and `else if` arguments to distinguish between faceted or list.

```
plot_group_vot <-  function(data = data,
                            group_var = group_var,
                            date_var = date,
                            unit = c("day", "week", "month", "quarter", "year"),
                            nrow = 2,
                            plot_type = c("facet", "list")){

  unit <- match.arg(unit)

  date_sym <- rlang::ensym(date_var)
  group_sym <- rlang::ensym(group_var)


  if (plot_type == "facet") {
    data <- data %>% dplyr::mutate(plot_date = lubridate::floor_date(!!date_sym, unit = unit),
                                   facet_var = !!group_sym)

    plot <- data %>%
      dplyr::count(plot_date, facet_var) %>%
      ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = plot_date, y = n, fill = facet_var)) +
      ggplot2::geom_col() +
      ggplot2::theme_minimal() +
      ggplot2::scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 months", date_labels = "%d-%b") +
      ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "none",
                     axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45),
                     panel.grid = element_blank()) +
      ggplot2::labs(title = "Topic Volume over Time", x = NULL, y = "Number of Posts") +
      ggplot2::facet_wrap(~facet_var, nrow = nrow)
    print(plot)

  } else if (plot_type == "list") {
    data <- data %>% dplyr::mutate(plot_date = lubridate::floor_date(!!date_sym, unit = unit),
                                   facet_var = !!group_sym)

    unique_groups <- data %>% pull(!!group_sym) %>% unique()
    plots <- list()

    for (group in unique_groups) {
      plot <- data %>%
        dplyr::filter(!!group_sym == group) %>%
        dplyr::count(plot_date) %>%
        ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = plot_date, y = n)) +
        ggplot2::geom_col() +
        ggplot2::theme_minimal() +
        ggplot2::scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 months", date_labels = "%d-%b") +
        ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "none",
                       axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45),
                       panel.grid = element_blank()) +
        ggplot2::labs(title = paste("Topic Volume over Time -", group), x = NULL, y = "Number of Posts")
      plots[[group]] <- plot
    }
    return(plots)

  } else {
    stop("Invalid plot_type argument. Try 'facet' or 'list'.")
  }
}
```

I have no error messages to provide but this is how I am calling this function.

```
plot_group_vot(data = data, group_var = group_var, date_var = date, unit = "day", plot_type = "list")
```

Comment: Your function will not *ascribe the same(or any) colour* in case of the list of plots as you are not mapping on the `fill` aes. Moreover, even when doing so you will not get the same colors as for the facetted plot. The colors are chosen based on the number of groups. And as you are creating a plot for each group you will only get one color per plot and it will be the same color for each plot.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the help Stefan! have posted the answer up now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help I managed resolve the problem, the issue was that I was not supplying a colour map representative of the groups in my group variable. So I had create one outside of the function like so:

```
colour_map <- c("group1" = "#colour1",
                "group2" = "#colour2", 
                "group3" = "#colour3")
```

Here is the section of the function where the changes are made, its the line `ggplot2::geom_col(fill = colour_mapping[group])` where the colour mapping is later called.

```
    for (group in unique_groups) {
      plot <- data %>%
        dplyr::filter(!!group_sym == group) %>%
        dplyr::count(plot_date) %>%
        ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = plot_date, y = n)) +
        ggplot2::geom_col(fill = colour_mapping[group]) +
        HelpR::theme_microsoft() +
        ggplot2::scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 months", date_labels = "%d-%b") +
        ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "none",
                       axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45),
                       panel.grid = element_blank()) +
        ggplot2::labs(title = paste("Topic Volume over Time -", group), x = NULL, y = "Number of Posts")

      plots[[group]] <- plot
    }
    return(plots)
```

This means that one would now use this function like so when wanting to render the plot list:

```
plot_group_vot(data = data, group_var = group_var, date_var = date, unit = "day", plot_type = "list", colour_mapping = colour_map)
```

The updated function is now as follows:.

```
plot_group_vot <- function(data = data,
                           group_var,
                           date_var,
                           unit = c("day", "week", "month", "quarter", "year"),
                           nrow = 2,
                           plot_type = c("facet", "list"),
                           colour_mapping = NULL) {

  unit <- match.arg(unit)

  date_sym <- rlang::ensym(date_var)
  group_sym <- rlang::ensym(group_var)

  if (plot_type == "facet") {
    data <- data %>% dplyr::mutate(plot_date = lubridate::floor_date(!!date_sym, unit = unit),
                                   facet_var = !!group_sym)

    plot <- data %>%
      dplyr::count(plot_date, facet_var) %>%
      ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = plot_date, y = n, fill = facet_var)) +
      ggplot2::geom_col() +
      HelpR::theme_microsoft() +
      ggplot2::scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 months", date_labels = "%d-%b") +
      ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "none",
                     axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45),
                     panel.grid = element_blank()) +
      ggplot2::labs(title = "Topic Volume over Time", x = NULL, y = "Number of Posts") +
      ggplot2::facet_wrap(~facet_var, nrow = nrow)

    print(plot)

  } else if (plot_type == "list") {
    data <- data %>% dplyr::mutate(plot_date = lubridate::floor_date(!!date_sym, unit = unit),
                                   facet_var = !!group_sym)

    unique_groups <- data %>% pull(!!group_sym) %>% unique()
    plots <- list()

    for (group in unique_groups) {
      plot <- data %>%
        dplyr::filter(!!group_sym == group) %>%
        dplyr::count(plot_date) %>%
        ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = plot_date, y = n)) +
        ggplot2::geom_col(fill = colour_mapping[group]) +
        HelpR::theme_microsoft() +
        ggplot2::scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 months", date_labels = "%d-%b") +
        ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "none",
                       axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45),
                       panel.grid = element_blank()) +
        ggplot2::labs(title = paste("Topic Volume over Time -", group), x = NULL, y = "Number of Posts")

      plots[[group]] <- plot
    }
    return(plots)

  } else {
    stop("Invalid plot_type argument. Try 'facet' or 'list'.")
  }
}
```